# All C:\ files have been moved to D:\ and windows not working

Tags: windows, windows-10

Today there was a problem in the hard desk that led to the system stopping
After that, the system did not work due to an error in the system files
I went to windows troubleshoot > command line
To find out what's wrong
I was surprised because c:\ didn't contain any files
Fortunately, I found partition D:\ containing all the files of C:
I don't know where this partition came from
The question here is how can I restore the system without losing any files
Or how can I make the system boot from partition D:
I don't want to reset the system because this happened to me in the past and all my files on C:\ were deleted

Comment: Best guess, it's booted from some type of recovery structure. C:\ is always the boot drive, which is why your data will now be showing as "not C". The data hasn't moved, the machine has booted from another source.

Comment: Make sure you have a good disk and set up Windows again on it. You cannot just "move" some major part of Windows from one disk to another. That will not work.

Comment: Does this mean that the files on D:\ will be deleted?

Comment: The disc is in good condition
Because I can read files from all partitions, but the problem here is that the files in C:\ are deleted

Comment: You need to set up Windows correctly and not governed by the location of files you have. Back these up to a USB Drive (not a USB Key) and then you can set up what you wish.

Comment: This is all just completely confusing the issue. The chances "all the files have moved" is absolutely nil.

Comment: @John I will do that
I hope it works out

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't see partition D:\ Do you have any idea where it came from or why the all file in C:\ moved to D:\

Comment: It didn't 'come from' anywhere, it's simply been relabelled because you are booted from something else. You have to figure out why it seems to have booted to some kind of emergency or recovery partition.

Comment: or the boot order was changed it is similar to the problem